# PHP mysql select date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a invoice type form submission and every submission has a date so I have created a varcha date field in mysql database to save the time.Time format is like '2011-06-26'.Now I need to select a range based on the date from my database.I tried following options but they don't display any result just blank page is displayed,even no errors.

Should I follow some special techniques on saving date to my database.If so please give me some explain about that because I am new to PHP and MYSQL development.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 'date' 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-06-02') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-06-25')




SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE 'date' 
BETWEEN CAST('2011-06-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2011-06-25' AS DATE)";
```

This is what I used to extract data

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row['tax']."<br>";
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL actually has a "date" type, so you don't need to use VARCHAR to store your dates

Comment: @matthewh

Ya I tried that also but still my result page is blank.Any ideas?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `DATETIME` type to store your date the trick is simple.
`DATETIME` allows you to store the date and the timestamp, however if only the date is specifed, timestamp will be stored as `00:00:00`

I'll show you a simple example.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test_table(
       id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
       test_date DATETIME,
       PRIMARY KEY (id));

mysql> INSERT INTO test_table(test_date) 
       VALUES('2011-06-26'), ('2011-05-14'), ('2011-05-02');

mysql> SELECT * FROM test_table;
+----+---------------------+
| id | test_date           |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2011-06-26 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2011-05-14 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | 2011-05-02 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test_date
       BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-05-31';
+----+---------------------+
| id | test_date           |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2011-05-14 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | 2011-05-02 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanx buddy.I tried but php result is still blank.This is my code of fetching data.

  $query="SELECT * FROM my_table 
            WHERE date BETWEEN 2011-06-02 AND 2011-06-25";
  $result=mysql_query($query);  
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $data=$row["tax"];
      echo $data;
  }

Comment: You put the dates between quotes, isn't it? I'm trying it on PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If the date column is of the TIMESTAMP or DATETIME type then the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 'date' 
BETWEEN '2011-06-02' AND '2011-06-25'
```

Edit: Sorry didn't see the column was a VARCHAR - you should change it to the DATETIME type to make things simpler.

Comment: I tried your solution buddy.But still I am getting a blank page as the result.Now this is how my date data is appears in the database after I altered that to DATETIME. > 2011-06-22 00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

1. Name of column - or without or in backticks
2. If date is varchar - also need cast date
   SELECT * FROM my_table 
   WHERE cast(`date`  as DATE)
   BETWEEN CAST('2011-06-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2011-06-25' AS DATE)";